# Getting null value after deserialization

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json.net, deserialization

I'm trying to get JSON data from Web API and then show it in tabular form in the MVC application.
But receiving null values after using deserialization.

JSON file :

```
[{
  "Students": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Ravi",
      "department": "IT"
    },

    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Raj",
      "department": "hr"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "avi",
      "department": "it"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "rome",
      "department": "HR"
    }
  ]
}]
```

```cs
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
} 
   

[HttpGet]
public async Task<List<Student>> GetAllStudents()
{
            
    /// Ostudent = new Student()
    using (var httpclient  = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var response = await httpclient.GetAsync("https://localhost:7232/api/Student"))
        {
            string res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                OStudents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Student>>(res);
        }
    }
    return OStudents ;
}
```

I'm trying to get value in response (`res`) but getting `null` from `OStudents`.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

Based on the latest JSON response, it is an array of `Root`.

You need to deserialize the JSON as the `List<Root>` and then extract the first `Root` object from the array. Then extract the `Students` list from the `Root` object.

```cs
public class Root
{
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
List<Root> roots = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(res);
List<Student> OStudents = roots[0].Students;
```

> Completed code:

```cs
public async Task<List<Student>> GetAllStudents()
{
            
    List<Student> OStudents = new List<Student>();
    using (var httpclient  = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var response = await httpclient.GetAsync("https://localhost:7232/api/Student"))
        {
            string res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            List<Root> roots = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(res);
            OStudents = roots[0].Students;
        }
    }
    return OStudents;
}
```

---

You may also work with `JArray` as:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

List<Student> OStudents = new List<Student>();
JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(json);
if (jArray.Count > 0)
{
    OStudents = jArray
        .First
        .SelectToken("Students")
        .ToObject<List<Student>>();
}
```

Comment: This is not working. It is showing nothing in output.

Comment: Did you try to debug the `res` value and see the value is matched as your posted JSON?

Comment: values is res :
[
 {"students":
  [
   {"id":1,"name":"Ravi","department":"IT"},
   {"id":2,"name":"Raj","department":"hr"},
   {"id":3,"name":"avi","department":"it"},
   {"id":4,"name":"rome","department":"HR"}
  ]
 }
]

Comment: Done updated the answer with the explanation.

Comment: Thank you @Yong Shun. It is working now.

Comment: I'm also trying to fetch data from json file using webapi. code for it is updated above. It works fine but if there is any another way do let me know.

Comment: I would suggest you create another question post but **not update the current question**. As the answer is aimed to solve the original question.